# Minimize redirects for www and HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, http-redirect

I want to redirect every request do https://www.example.com/request

It's already working, but I want to minimize the redirects. Currently I got 2 redirects: http://example.com -> https://example.com -> https://www.example.com

Every other case is working with 0 or 1 redirect.

My .htaccess contains the following (generated by "Easy HTTPS (SSL) Redirection" WordPress Plugin):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it for my own

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com.*
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```